# Importing project from svn failed again and again

Tags: eclipse, svn, svnkit

I use eclipse `Version: Helios Service Release 2`and `Build id: 20110218-0911`. And my subversive svn connector is `SVNKit 1.2.3. r5745(for SVN 1.5.6, all platforms)`. And I'm new to subversion control system.
Every time I try to import project from svn, it start checkout slowly and failed after 90% with this message.

[image: error message]

I have tried many times but still I got the above message and checkout failed at after 90%.

But when I try to checkout that same url from `tortoise svn`, its ok and may be file size is around 229MB and takes around 30 minutes.

I don't know why my importing project from eclipse using subversive is very slow and failed again and again.

Here is the list of installed software in my eclipse.

[image: list of install software]

And the svn connector image.

[image]

I don't want to use tortoise svn in this project because all of my co-worker used eclipse subversive. So, I'm worries of conflict and some error if I used tortoise svn instead of eclipse subversive.
I'm very appreciate for any solution and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use **very old** SVNKit version. That's why there are no problems in more up-to-date TortoiseSVN, but there are in Eclipse IDE.

Upgrade Subversive and its connectors to solve the problem: https://eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php

Comment: When I try to update subversive and svn connector, I got dependency error. Should I need to update eclipse before update subversive and svn connector?

Comment: I got this error `Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.` when I try to update my subversive and svn connector. So, should I need to update my eclipse? Please help me.

Comment: @Cloud. I regret to say this, but I can't provide you with any instruction on this matter. Just upgrade SVNKit and if it requires to upgrade Eclipse or other components, upgrade them too.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. Now, I installed Aptana and install updated subversive svn. Now, its ok and I can checkout.